# css full height of container as full height of the background image

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I am building a responsive landing page with bootstrap. so far i have [this page](http://ari.seveloff.com/test/). i came across a problem. the full height of the container does not mach the full height of the background image. in order to maintain a full responsive landing page i use a real image as background image.

the question is how to make the container get the height of the image in order to maintain the percents mach all devices an landscape view like in [this example](http://www.strauss-water-campaign.co.il/52667_tami4_per_500K/)

this is the source code
css

```
html{
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    border: 0;
    vertical-align: baseline;

}


body{
    zoom: 1;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    border: 0;
    outline: 0;
    width: 100%;
}
}



.center{
    text-align: center;
    margin: 0 auto;
}


.container{
    background: url('../images/bgm.jpg') no-repeat scroll contain;
    background-size:  100%; 
    height: 100% !important;
    width: 100% !important;
}


.bgm{  
    z-index: -9999;
    top: 0;1
    position: absolute;
    width: 100%;
    right: 0;
}


    #logo{
        background-color: red;
    }

    #dail{
        background-color: blue;
    }

    #header{
        height: 15%;
    }

    #text-h{
        height: 12%;
    }
    #para{
        height: 7%;
    }
    #header{
        height: 15%;
    }


    .red{
        background-color: red;
    }

    .green{
        background-color: green;
    }
```

html

```
<html lang="en"><head>


    <meta charset="utf-8">

    <title>דירות קו ראשון לים בפנמה</title>
    <meta name="description" content="דירות קו ראשון לים בפנמה">

    <script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="http://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery-backstretch/2.0.4/jquery.backstretch.min.js"></script>
    <link href="http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Open+Sans:400,600,700,300" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="//maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.1/css/bootstrap.min.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/bootstrap-rtl/3.2.0-rc2/css/bootstrap-rtl.css">

    <link href="//maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.2.0/css/font-awesome.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/style.css">
<!--    <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://fonts.googleapis.com/earlyaccess/notosanshebrew.css"> -->



    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, height=device-height, initial-scale=1.0, maximum-scale=2.0, user-scalable=yes">
    <!--    <script src="js/jquery.backstretch.js"> -->

    <!--[if lt IE 9]>
  <script src="http://html5shiv.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/html5.js"></script>
  <![endif]-->
</head>

<body cz-shortcut-listen="true">


    <div class="container">

        <img src="images/bgm.jpg" class="bgm">

        <div class="row" id="header">
            <div class="col-lg-4 col-md-6 col-xs-6  center" id="logo">
asdasdasd               
            </div>  
            <div class="col-lg-4 col-md-6 col-xs-6 center" id="dail">
asdasdasd
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="row" id="text-h">
            <div class="col-lg-4 col-md-8 col-xs-8 col-offset-4 center red" id="h1">
asdasdasd               
            </div>  

        </div>

        <div class="row" id="para">

            <div class="col-lg-4 col-md-12 col-xs-12 center green" id="par">
asdasdasd               
            </div>  
        </div>

        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-lg-4 col-md-12 center main red">

        <form method="POST" d id="form" action="form.php">

                    <input id="name" maxlength="40" name="name" size="20" type="text" placeholder="שםי" required>



                    <input id="phone" maxlength="40" name="phone" size="20" type="text"  placeholder="טלפון" required>

                    <input id="email" maxlength="80" name="email" size="20" type="email" placeholder="אימייל" required>

                </form>
            </div>  
        </div>
        </div>

    </body>
</html>
```

tnx

Comment: post the source code

Comment: edded at the question

Answer (score 1):

use

```
background-size: cover;
```

instead of 100%.

Comment: sorry but the at the codepen the image is above the bootstrap container